# Has anyone displayed a Salesforce Dashboard component on WordPress site? If so, how?

Tags: wordpress, salesforce, integration

I work for a nonprofit which help disabled military veterans. We have all our participants register with us using Salesforce as the repository of their registrations. We have dashboard components in Salesforce Lighting which totals up the number of active participants we have. I would like to display the component on our WordPress site but have never done anything like that before. I was hoping to find someone who has done something like that and offer some direction on how to go about doing it.

I tried looking up WordPress plugins which integrate with Salesforce. Most seem to be geared towards sending registrations back and forth but not displaying information. From a little bit of research, it seems like coding might need to be involved. Maybe doing a REST API with a Post option which will send the data through an HTTP URI? But to my understanding is that it would require WordPress to be an API. I am sure there are gaps in my logic.

I dont have an extensive amount of programing language experience but am willing to learn. I have taken a few Java and JavaScript classes in school.

I have not attempted this yet. I am just looking for feedback and direction.

Answer (score 1):

Few options here, in no specific order...

Do Wordpress users have real Salesforce accounts or is their data simply stored in SF? Ask your Salesforce admin if there's a "**customer community**" configured (if your SF org is really old he might refer to it as customer portal). Communities offer nice way of exposing SF to poeple who don't need full SF user licenses. Think like collaborating with real SF users on "My Cases", viewing reports & dashboards... But for this you'd really need people logged in to SF so it won't work if you want just something anonymous. [Some more info](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115373/expose-report-dashboard-data-into-public-sites)

Another option might be using **Sites** (Visualforce pages that expose SF data to guest users). Think like displaying a product catalog, FAQ, web-to-lead form or some other generic "contact us" page that's anonymous. So if you have SF developer (or admin with good copy-paste skills) you could use some Visualforce charts. They can be 100% coded (like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm)) or fed data from a report (like [this](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_vf_charts.htm)) so it's simpler for admin to change the report filters or something without really writing code. Not sure if the simple route will work on a Site, [there are some old answers that say "No"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67113/problem-using-analyticsreportchart-in-force-com-site), you might have to try it out. Worst case you'd need Apex code (or JavaScript) to query SF for results and display them. And display that SF Site page as `<iframe>` in Wordpress.

A slight twist on the Sites option - do you use Chatter (bit like Twitter inside SF)? There's way to take a snapshot of a report when a milestone has been met and post it to chatter ("congrats for hitting X participants"). And embed feeds on Visualforce pages too. [Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dashboards_post_to_dashboard_feed.htm&type=5)

What SF edition you're on (Group/Professional/Enterprise...)? If you have API access to Salesforce you could **query the info yourself** from Wordpress and display it using whatever charting library's easiest for you (Google Charts, Flot...). There are tons of examples how to connect to SF from PHP (or maybe you could cannibalize a WP plugin). Technically it's one POST message to log in to SF and one GET to run a query (something as simple as `SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE isActive__c = true`?)

That'd be more or less everything in terms of pulling data out of Salesforce. I mean if you have API access enabled you can slice & dice it how you want, extract data with raw PHP code or use some middleware but overall idea doesn't change. Write queries yourself or use "Analytics API" to access report results (so your administrator has power to change it without coding)...

---

So how about **pushing**? SF could notify you about current participants count. At scheduled intervals or even realtime. That'd be "just" raw data though, you'd have to write visualisation yourself.

Plenty of options here

- **workflow rules** (code-free), sends XML message to specified URL so you'd need a WP page that can "capture" the result. Could be sent on creation of new record or update of existing. Won't give you totals, it'd be data related to that particular record so you'd have to build kind of +1 / -1 counter... Or if you use a report + analytic snapshot (helper object to store report results) and have workflow on that - that could be really close to what's needed.
- **scheduled apex job** to run some queries and send the results to you. Again - you'd need a WP url that can be called from SF
- if there's a CometD plugin for Wordpress you should look at Salesforce Streaming API, Platform Events or (newer and even simpler to configure) Change Data Capture. Basically you "subscribe" to a topic (a SF query) and whenever SF data changes and SF decides it'd change the results of the query - it'd push the results to you. It's **almost realtime**. Too much to write about them, perhaps best if you'd try to click through some trailheads - SF self-paced training courses:

  - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_streaming
  - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture
  - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics

Comment: Thanks for your response @eyescream. In my mind, we wouldn't want visitors of our site to be issued logins. We just want to be able to display statistical up-to-date numbers on our metrics to our constituents. That way anyone who visits our site can see those numbers. By issuing a community login we would be limited to sharing the data with those who only have logins. I think the IFrame is more along the lines of what we are looking for. Or even more so probably the GET or POST requests. I just need to learn get my hands dirty with it.

Comment: @AlexWeitz, did you ever come up with a solution for this? I know it's a year and half later, but I'm trying to accomplish the same thing was hoping you might have some code to share if it's still accessible. Interestingly enough, I am also doing this for a nonprofit helping disabled folks. :)